# How does is.null work on list elements in R?

Tags: r, list, null

In my script I am checking if a list element exists. I was doing this with the `is.null` function. However, something odd happens:

When I create a list with two elements called **date1** and **date2**, `TRUE`is returned when I check if the element **date** is `NULL`.

```
test = list()
test$date1 = 1
test$date2 = 2
is.null(test$date) #  TRUE
```

However, when I create a list which contains the element **date1**, `FALSE` is returned when I check if the element **date** is `NULL`.

```
test2 = list()
test2$date1 = 1
test2$month = 2
is.null(test2$date) #  FALSE
```

How is this possible? I am using *R version 3.4.4*

Comment: it's due to partial matching. In your first example, `date` can match `date1` or `date2` while in the second, it necessarily refers to `date1`

Comment: @Cath You seem to be right.  `test$dates` was in fact `null`, but `test$date` was `[1]`.

Comment: @Cath then why doesn't it partially match in the first case?

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren because it is either `date1` or `date2` hence it matches neither